RabbitMQ: Reading single message from queue based on correlation id using java
Looking for solution to read single message from queue where each message is stored with correlationId.
Code snippet to publish message with correlation id into queue.
public static void publishMessage(String url, Map<String, Object> headers) {
        Connection connection = QueueConnetionFactory.getConnection();
        try {
            Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
            String correlationId = "UniqueId;
            channel.basicPublish("", RESPONSE_QUEUE_NAME, new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder()
                       .headers(headers)
                       .correlationId(correlationId)
                       .build(), url.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + url + "'");
    }

public static String readMessageFromResponseQueue(String corrId) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, IOException {
        final CompletableFuture<String> response = new CompletableFuture<>();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
        channel.queueDeclare(RESPONSE_QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
        DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
            try {
                if (delivery.getProperties().getCorrelationId().equals(corrId)) {
                    System.out.println("Got response.................");
                    response.complete(new String(delivery.getBody(), "UTF-8"));
                }
            } finally {
                channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
            }
        };
        String ctag = channel.basicConsume(Constants.RESPONSE_QUEUE_NAME, true, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> {
        });
        String result = response.get();
        channel.basicCancel(ctag);
        return result;
    }

Above code reads all message from queue and its keeps running.
Looking for solution to read single message and it should stop reading other message..

is it queuing concept to read a single message from queue ?
